How do I remove my selection?
I'm trying to paste something on this layer, but it always pastes inside of this yellow selection box. How I remove it ?


Looks like you are using GIMP, which you forgot to mention. For future reference please remember to tag your questions with the software you are using.
Anyway, back to the question . . .
That isn't a selection. It's the layer boundary. The layer boundary (yellow dotted line) shows the extent of the region that contains editable pixels. The area outside has no pixels to edit. In GIMP layers can be a different size from the image (or canvas).
Worth noting that in GIMP selections are displayed using a line with white dotted marching ants.
There are several ways for dealing with the layer boundary isse.

You can switch off the display of the layer boundary by clicking View > Show Layer Boundary (this toggles it on and off). This will do nothing to the layer boundary itself, it will just hide the yellow dotted line. I don't recommend this, because knowing where the layer boundary is located is important in GIMP.

You can select a different layer, or create a new layer. The layer boundary shows for the selected layer. When you paste you can then anchor the floating selection to the selected layer (the Anchor button is in the Layers panel)

You can fix the layer size problem by doing Layer > Layer to Image size. This will convert the layer size to the size of the entire image (the canvas). Then when you paste it will work as expected.

Alternatively you can paste, then hit the New Layer Icon in the Layers panel to promote the pasted content (floating selection) to its own layer.

You can also bypass all of that and just do Edit > Paste As > New Layer - however, if what you are pasting is smaller or larger than the image you are pasting into, it will come in with a layer boundary that is a different size from the image. So to fix that you can then also do step 3 shown above.



A guess: It's not a selection. Some programs show the actual size of the active layer(=selected in the Layers panel)  with a dashed borderline. The border doesn't vanish by applying Select > None. I guess your layer size is smaller than the image size. That's possible for ex. in GIMP.
Layer >  Layer  to image size makes the layer to cover the full image area. Try it.
